nodejs bash child process, xclip invalid URL
I have a nodejs app that spawns a bash shell in a child process.
the problem part:
let fireFoxUrl = execSync(`xclip -selection primary -o -t text/x-moz-url-priv 2> /dev/null`);

console.log(fireFoxUrl) displays a normal looking url, however
try {
    const parsedUrl = new URL(fireFoxUrl);
} catch (error) {
    console.log("new URL error: ", error);
}

says that it's an invalid url.
The console.log("new URL error: ", error);

output:
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL',
  input: 'h\x00t\x00t\x00p\x00s\x00:\x00/\x00/\x00w\x00w\x00w\x00.

... an so on
Not sure how to fix this, any ideas?

Avoid use of 2>/dev/nul for debugging!!

It smells like an XY Problem! What are you trying to do?

extract the url from primary -o -t text/x-moz-url-priv to modify the exifdata on jpeg using exiftool

Why nodejs? (NB: output look like UFT-16)

why not nodejs?....... I've done a test on the fireFoxUrl and the string length = 164, whereas the same url but copied directly from the firefox address bar the length = 82

Because I don't see what json could add... The whole job could represent a short bash script (even POSIX shell) smaller than 30 lines.

With the shebang (POSIX: #!/bin/sh), 5 line will suffice! Something like: xclip -selection clip -o -t text/x-moz-url-priv | recode -f u7..u8 | xargs wget -qO - | exiftool -j -

I've just posted a full clipDump function with some samples at Pipe to/from the clipboard in a Bash script!

thanks for the link to the bash clip explanation, I'll check it out

so, xclip -sel p -o -t text/x-moz-url-priv  | tr -d '\\0' 2> /dev/null
did the job, thanks! I've only added the single quotes '\\0',
and
parsedUrl = new URL(fireFoxUrl);

gives me a nice JS URL object to work with.

This will probably work fine for plain ASCII, but break horribly for non-ASCII strings. You are looking for something like iconv -f utf-16le instead of tr
